problem in displaying a table on the right position on top of the page in latex
I am writing in latex and I want my table to be displayed on top of a page that I wrote it however I don't know for what reason it shows it on top of next page. here is the table that I have:
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
   \caption{}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{vType} & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f}& \textbf{g} \\
    \hline
     \hline
    t & 2.6 & 4.5 & 0.5 & 90 & 0.1 & - & -\\
  %  \hline
    x & 3 & 4.5 & 0.5 & 80 & 0.1 & - & -\\
  \label{tab:atts}
\end{table*}

I also should display the following figure in the same page. I don't know if it has conflict with the table
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=4cm]{Figure/Integrated-figs.png} % Adjust the width and height as needed
\caption{V}
\label{fig:disp}
\end{figure}

Here is the packages I am using in latex:
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{placeins}

I appreciate if any one can suggest me a solution for it.

Please don't post a bunch of code fragments. Make one small, but compilable [mre]

You probably want to move your table to before the start of the page where it should be at the top.
